# priority based resource choice condition in seize block (ressourcePool and packages as agents)

Tags: anylogic

I have three different resource pool and i initialized for each resource pool a priority.

For example ResourcePool1 On new unit: int priority = 0; priority = 1;

Now I want to initialize my resource condition.

That means exactly:
All AGVs that are in Node1 should be considered, since all AGVs return to Node1 after the order has been processed.

If all AGVs are present, then AGV3 of resource pool3 should be selected with priority 3 before AGV2 before AGV1.

Another rule that is already initialised in the code should also be taken into account. [image: function]

Since you can only enter one condition for the resource choice condition, I would like to combine the two functions in one function.

I have not been able to get any code to work. I tried to create a function that retrieves my available AGV in node1 and include it in the function f_AGVchoiceCondition, but this did not work.

Does anyone have any advice on how to approach this problem or what code I need to do this?

THANK YOU :)